# How can I refactor in VS Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, refactoring

This might be an inappropriate place to ask this question but in VS Code I can't find the option to refactor. There is an option to "replace all" but that seems to be more like a "find/replace" method that only looks at the document I'm in. I'd like it to refactor all references to the method throughout the program.

Here are a couple of images.

[image: Right Click]

[image: Edit Tab]

Comment: You might be looking for the [Rename Symbol](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring#_rename-symbol) feature. But, as of now, it seems it's not yet available for C++ and it's still an [open feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/296) for the vscode-cpptools extension.